# NVARCHAR(MAX) to datetime conversion (SQL SERVER 2012)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table in which a column is nvarchar(Max) and date value is stored as for eg: 'Tue Aug 22 00:00:00 PDT 2017'

How do I convert this value to proper datetime value

I tried 
Try_Convert, Try_parse,Parse but all fail to convert it to datetime

Any help or suggestion

Comment: When you say it fails, do you mean you get an error, or that it doesn't convert properly?

Comment: I get error as the column because the column also contains other text values so I was filter only the values which was date but their conversion to actual date failed

Comment: @Ranjeet - Please edit this question to add this info; I'd also suggest adding some example values of the actual contents of the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` value, and of the results from your filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to perform some string manipulation to get it to convert properly.  If all of your strings are fixed width and follow the same pattern as provided in your example, the following is a possible way to get the conversion to work:

```
DECLARE @myString NVARCHAR(50) = N'Tue Aug 22 00:00:00 PDT 2017'

--                       Month and Day              + Year                + HH:MM:SS using I assume 24 hour clock
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@myString, 5, 7) + RIGHT(@myString, 4) + SUBSTRING(@myString, 11, 10))
```

If your data shows any pattern variances, please append some additional examples to your question.

Comment: I tried using the below with success  TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(REPLACE(columname,'PDT ',''),'00:00:00 ','') AS DATE)

Comment: There's a number of different approaches you can use, so I'm glad you found something that works.  :)